# Graded rings: what does $\mathbb{Z}[y]/(y, y^{2n + 1})$ with $y$ of degree $2$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-rings

I do not understand what $\mathbb{Z}[y]/(2y, y^{2n + 1})$ with $y$ of degree $2$ means.

If I read the Wikipedia page right, the graded ring $\mathbb{Z}[y]$ is the set of all polynomials in $y$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ with the natural multiplication, $(2y, y^{2n + 1})$ is the ideal generated by $(2y, y^{2n + 1})$.

Then $\mathbb{Z}[y]/(y, y^{2n + 1})$ is $\bigoplus(R_i + I)/I$ with the canonical multiplication, where $R$ is all polynomials of the form $z y^i$, $I$ is the ideal $(y, y^{2n + 1})$ and $R_i + I = \{a + b \ | \ a \in R_i, b \in I\}$.

Question 2: Wouldn't that mean that $(R_i + I)/I \cong R$ because $[a + b] = [a]$ in $(R_i + I)/I$?

Question 3: What does $y$ of degree 2 mean?

Edit: A bit more context may help:

I need to find an isomorphism of graded rings

$$H^*(\mathbb{R}P^{2n}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[y]/(2y, y^{2n + 1})$$

Comment: So in the question you were actually interested in there is a coefficient of 2 which changes things.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, that was a typo. Thank you. That only leaves questions 2 and 3. I just read in Hatcher that degree of $y$ is $n$ means that $y$ is an element of the $n$'th component of the decomposition. How does that make sense when $y$ is an element of the 1st component under the standard decomposition of the ring of polynomials in $y$?

Comment: It makes sense because the standard decomposition is just a choice we make, and there is no reason we cannot make a different choice (which we do in this case, to make the isomorphism be one of graded rings, rather than just one of rings).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So what the comment "$y$ of degree 2" really means is that we put a zero module before $\langle 1 \rangle$ in the decomposition?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. You still want the constants to be in degree $0$ (in fact, you have to). You just double all the usual degrees. As to "why" you do this: That will hopefully become clear once you do the exercise.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I see, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Of course, $y^{2n+1}$ lies in the principal ideal generated by $y$, and hence is a redundant (or superfluous) generator. Also, the corresponding quotient ring is clearly isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.